# loop setinterval stopping javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my code.

This is probably a dumb question, but I really need help!

Thank you, and here is my code:

```
<script>
function dodat(){
var btn=document.createElement("div");
btn.style.width="25px";
btn.style.height="25px";
btn.style.backgroundColor="red";
btn.style.boxShadow="inset 0px 0px 0px 2px black";
btn.style.position="absolute";
btn.style.left="0px";
mycars = new Array();
numba = Math.round(Math.random()*1000);
btn.id=numba;
mycars[numba] = 0;
setInterval('mycars[numba] = mycars[numba]+1;document.getElementById(numba).style.left=mycars[numba];', '10');

document.getElementById("track").appendChild(btn);
}
</script>

<body>

<div style="background-color:#c3c3c3;width:500px;height:25px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;" id="track"></div>
</body>

<script>
setInterval("dodat();", "1000");
</script>
```

I want it so that when a new blob is called, the last one continues until it goes into the end of the other side, instead it stops when a new one is called.

I'm okay with any solution, JavaScript, jQuery or whatever you please. :)

Comment: I tried to fix it by making an array, so that the variable with the count which increments how far an element is going doesn't get reset when a new one is made, but that's not the case :\ please help thx

Comment: As the below answer states, your `setInterval` must be wrapped in a function (the one inside `dodat()` -- Also, you're creating a new array of `mycars` each time, which is local to that function -- think about it.

Comment: Doesn't work! http://jsfiddle.net/F9TUz/1/ :( @tymeJV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setInterval function is off. setInterval take a function and a time (milliseconds)

```
setInterval(function(){
  //code
}, 30000);
```

Comment: you're sure? i don't want it to be really long, I want a new one to be called quickly

Comment: You can change the number to the amount of milliseconds you want. 1000 will fire once every second.

Comment: setInterval takes either a function or a string. If a string it will be compiled with the Function() constructor. But it is better with a function since the compilation happens only once instead of each loop. It is also better for readability since maintaining code in strings is silly. But it is incorrect to say that passing the string is wrong. It's just bad practice.

Comment: It isn't moving because when you set left to a number you need to add "px" to the end. So document.getElementById(numba).style.left=mycars[numba]+"px"; I don't know exactly what your trying to do but that will get the boxes moving on the page.

Comment: @user3092778: Is this what you were trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/F9TUz/9/

Comment: Note that you're not seeing the rest of your "cars" because you set the height of the track to show only one car.

Comment: I added `+"px"` to `style.left`. Removed `height:25px` from `track` and added `var` to `numba` (otherwise it would be a shared global var and all the setInterval would be operating on it which means that only the last added car would move). Oh and also changed position to `relative` for cars otherwise the height of the track would be calculated as zero which would hide all cars - alternatively you can set the height of the track and use position `absolute`.

Comment: This is the alternative version with position absolute and height of track set to 25px - http://jsfiddle.net/F9TUz/11/

Answer (score 1):

if you want to keep the format you have try:

`setInterval(step,timeToStep)`;

In this case step is a function

```
var step = function(){ ... };
```

and time is just a your time

```
var timeToStep = 1000;
```

or even set it to a var like

```
stepping  = setInterval(step,timeToStep);
```

this way you could call clear interval in a more clear way ,if you like `clearInterval(stepping);`,

Comment: setInterval takes either a function or a string. If a string it will be compiled with the Function() constructor. But it is better with a function since the compilation happens only once instead of each loop. It is also better for readability since maintaining code in strings is silly. But it is incorrect to imply that passing the string is wrong.

Comment: I just replaced your step implementation with var step = function(){alert("hello")};

this gives me an alert window every sec. So it seems that the issue is with your function. What are you trying to implement ?